# How can I store JSON data on Azure Websites?

Tags: json, azure, nosql, azure-storage

I wish to have an JSON-like object store - like Mongo or similar for an app currently deployed on  Windows Azure Websites. My data is shaped like objects, so I like my database to be shaped similarly.

From http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/ I know Azure supports either 'SQL Database' (which I guess is Microsoft SQL?) or MySQL. But can the versions provided store and query JSON type data?

As my app is relatively small (ie, it fits into memory), storing JSON blobs might also be an option.

Comment: You missed out on Table Storage which is NoSql data store in Windows Azure: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/.

Comment: @guarav The docs say Table Storage is for 'non structured' data, which I presumes means not JSON objects.

Comment: Azure Table Storage is a key/value pair store (much like Amazon DynamoDB). With the latest changes to storage service announced yesterday, you can work with JSON objects and save them as key/value pair in Azure table storage.

Comment: @guarav Thanks, but I need to be able to query JSON structures within the value, so it doesn't sound like that's an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT Nov 2019** [CosmosDB Mongo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction) is now available as a native Azure document-database service (e.g. JSON).

**Original answer below**

Azure will let you store data any way you want. As @Gaurav stated, you can take advantage of Table storage, which lets you put any type of data within its properties (feel free to store JSON strings in its properties), and with the [new storage updates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx), you can even retrieve contents as JSON. For larger content, you can store objects in blob storage and reference the URI from your table entities.

If you want something like MongoDB, you can either install MongoDB in a Virtual Machine (where you'll incur the costs and maintenance of the VM) or take advantage of a hosting provider such as MongoLab, which offers free, shared, and dedicated MongoDB offerings via both the Azure Store and  via their own website.

You won't be able to install a storage service on Azure Web Sites, but you can easily access any type of storage described above (or numerous other options, like installing MySQL or other databases).

Comment: Sure, any DB can store a string, but can I query the JSON like a normal object database such as Mongo? Can I access MongoLab / a MongoDB VM via WebSites or do I have to move to the Virtual Machines product?

Comment: Table storage will not facilitate queries against stored JSON strings - that's where MongoDB shines. You can access anything you want from Web Sites; you just need a database connection string.

Comment: Thanks @david. Looks like accessing a MongoDB VM from Azure Websites might be the way to go.

Comment: Azure Store offers MongoDB on Azure (DBaaS).

Comment: Azure SQL Database also supports JSON.

Comment: Update 2017: DocumentDB is now Cosmos DB - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dear-documentdb-customers-welcome-to-azure-cosmos-db/

Comment: @mikemaccana - 1) the question by the OP is now off-topic (broad, tool/service recommendation), where it wasn't off-topic 6 years ago, and should just be close-voted, which I have now done. And 2) Please post your own answer next time, instead of deleting and rewriting the entirety of mine. Especially on something upvoted and accepted. Rolled back accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon 1. it's asking for how to store something, not a product recommendation. It's not like Azure provides multiple databases. 2 I just edited your amendment to DocumentDB (since the link didn't work anymore) and removed the old info (since it's no longer relevant) which I thought conveyed the spirit of your answer. I've now changed the answer to have a current amendment with a working link, but kept your original answer.